# Possible to reverse the argument order in async.apply?

Tags: javascript, node.js

From the async documentation:

> ### apply(function, arguments..)
>
> Creates a continuation function with some arguments already applied.
>
> Useful as a shorthand when combined with other control flow functions. Any arguments passed to the returned function are added to the arguments originally passed to apply.

... and their example with arguments passed in:

```
node> var fn = async.apply(sys.puts, 'one');
node> fn('two', 'three');
one
two
three
```

I want to do something like this:

```
async.waterfall([
    async.apply(db.getSomeData, 'foo', 'bar'),
    async.apply(async.map, bazParser)
], callback);
```

However, because the method signature of `async.map()` is `(arr, iterator, [callback])`, `bazParser` becomes the first argument passed to `async.map()`, as opposed to the intended data returned from `db.getSomeData()`.

I always remember this by telling myself `async.apply()` appends "my stuff first" to the arguments list, but is there any way to reverse this, so that the **returned data** gets passed-in first, followed by any parameters I pass into `async.apply()`?

Right now the only way I can do this is thusly:

```
async.waterfall([
    async.apply(db.getSomeData, 'foo', 'bar'),
    function(dbData, next) {     //   <==
        async.map(dbData, bazParser, next);
    }     //   <==
], callback);
```

Would love to get rid of the two extra lines if possible. *insert acknowledgement that compact "clever" code is an anti-pattern*

### tl;dr

Change `async.apply()` so it behaves like "Any arguments passed to the returned function are *prepended* to the arguments originally passed to apply."?

Comment: Did you try something with `apply` or `call` *(the native ones, not the ones built into Async)*? Something like `async.map.apply(thisvalue, arguments_array)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that only if modified the core of async on your project.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much, but there was always a possibility that I could use `async` a different way to achieve what I want. Never hurts to ask.